# Input math in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, symbolic-math

In many desktop or web applications like GeoGebra, Microsoft Word, Wolfram Alpha, and Maple there is a way to input math formulas like these in figure 1. but when I tried to program a calculator that does symbolic calculations and enables the users to input math formulas by pressing buttons to add each notation I couldn't find a way to program that in PyQt5.

[image]

**figure 1**

### What I tried

I tried many Ideas like:

1. Make the math input consists of QSvgWidgets and QLineEdit widgets using Matplotlib and latex and Sympy but I found it very hard to place the QLineEdit widgets in the right place and very complex to deal with formulas after the input process and there were many other problems that made this so hard to program
2. Using Unicode Instead of QSvgWidgets but I couldn't find a way to make nested formulas like these in figure 2 and I couldn't find a way to make the integrals and the sigma notations like in figure 3 because it was hard to place the dotted-square-placeholders in the top and underneath the notations.
   [image]
   **figure 2**
   [image]
   **figure 3**

I really don't know where to start and what is the right tool or the method that does this. I even thought of using JS libraries like MathJax somehow but I don't know much about JS and I think that Python is powerful enough to let me program this.

Any ideas or code examples will be very useful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You said "enables the users to input math formulas by pressing buttons". Do you mean that the user presses a button and then you want to display an "input box" at specific positions based on the mathematical function?

Comment: @musicamante Yes exactly and the mathematical notation will appear too and in each "input box" the user can input other formulas inside like in figure 2.

Comment: Then it's a bit complex, as you can only do that by manually positioning the input widgets. Creating an editor like this is *not* an easy task, and requires both deep knowledge and experience of both libraries: Qt *and* whatever you're going to use to draw the symbols (if it's matplotlib, then LaTex).

Comment: Interesting question, however, as you know, this is a very complex problem. My advice is to look at open source projects for math, and see how they approached this problem. Ideally you would be able to adapt their code to your purposes, but at least maybe you can see what libraries and general approach they used. If you find any such projects, you could ask on their developer forum or mailing list for advice.

Comment: @musicamante Now I am actually working on the first approach but as you said it's really very complex for me to program this but when I look at these applications It seems like it must be a way easier and more efficient than manually positioning the widgets.

Comment: @RobertDodier I actually searched on Github but it seems like all the projects are written in JS and the only project that was in Python is using natural language to input math like using " ^ " to refer to powers and " / " to frictions however I will take your advice seriously and I will intensify my search and look at more projects. Thanks for your advice.